# Weinre how to add new targets?

Tags: javascript, ios, debugging, weinre

Hello I am new to Weinre and I need to debug my website which seems to act strange when opened using an IOS platform.
 So I am using Weinre to debug it. I installed the tool and tested it running with the demo targets in the server itself.
 Now I need to add my website as a target and run it with an iphon (or ipad) and debug it with Weinre. I don't know how to add my website as a target, I cannot manually add the

```
<script src="http://123.456.7.89:8080/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous"></script>
```

script (do not have permission to manually change the page). so How can I do my debugging with Weinre?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a bookmarklet.  The main weinre server page actually has a bookmarklet in it, for itself, that you should be able to use directly, if you can figure out how to set up a bookmarklet for your device.  This seems to change release-release for mobile browsers, so you might want to do a google search on "bookmarklet" and your device's name or the OS release, to see if anyone has any tips.